# Android Viewpager Performance

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am currently using a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePager` adapter, with approx 25 different fragments (and different `relativelayouts`). When I scroll I generally notice substantial lag when swiping to some views, except when I declare `viewpager.setoffscreenpagelimit(25)`. Is there a way to increase performance of this `viewpager`, without having all the pages loaded at all time?

Comment: You notice substantial what? One thing you could always try is to experiment with different numbers in the `offscreenpagelimit` parameter, which means problem pages will be loaded before you get to them

Comment: sorry, i notice substancial lag

Answer (score 3):

Using the ViewPager out of the box will load a maximum of three Fragments/Views. Stay with that number. It is not the ViewPager that is slow, you are doing something in your code that makes it slow. Does any of your Fragment do any blocking or CPU-consuming task? For instance loading Bitmaps? Are you having some parsing that could be done in an AsyncTask? Maybe you could put such things else where and save it to a database and then when you load the Frament it will stay very clean and efficient if reading from a database.

Comment: well yes,each fragment has a different relativelayout and a different background to it, that I load in the onCreateView().Other thant that I only have a couple of buttons and imageviews (also loaded on the onCreateView())

Comment: Have you tried on a real device and if so, which? Trying on the emulator is generally very slow.

Comment: i am using a couple devices, a nexus 7 and a galaxy nexus

Comment: Are you doing anything in the Activity? It could be that you have some CPU-consuming stuff in the background and thus make the app slow overall.

Comment: in the activity i only declare the pager and set the pager adapter

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add more detail to your question? For example, what are you doing in each pages?

Have you updated to latest [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)?

Changes for v4 support library:

- Improved interaction behavior for ViewPager.
- Fixed a bug that could cause ViewPager to select the wrong page.
- Fixed use of removeView() method during layout for ViewPager.
- Fixed issue with SearchViewCompat where using the back button to dismiss does not clear the search text. This fix only applies to host API levels 14 and higher.

You have always to remember that FragmentStatePagerAdapter auto-save pages and remove them when not used. So if you swipe very fast there will be a lot of load/unload of pages. You can try to increase the amount of pages loaded in memory.

Comment: I havent updated to the latest support library, will try that and leave some feedback. I basically have some Relative Layouts, each with a different image as a background, and some imageviews as interaction points, thats all.  I am not doing any network related tasks in the ui thread.